# clear clipboard in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, clipboard

In my extension, I'm writing something to clipboard and then pasting it.
After the job is done, I would like to clear clipboard to prevent possible privacy/security issues (maybe user was dealing with some logins,passwords etc...)
I could simply write `...` or `abc` to clipboard, but it would be much better to simply wipe it.
Is that possible in Chrom(iums) like clearData in IE?

trying to write empty string to dummy textarea that is used as placeholder won't do good.

```
txtArea.value = '';
txtArea.focus();
txtArea.select();
document.execCommand('Copy');
```

....nothing is copied to clipboard. Same if I use
 `txtArea.value = null;`

Comment: No such command in [HTML Editing API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#miscellaneous-commands).

Comment: I don't even know a way to do it on my os… edit : now I do :)